# Dianoga implementation issue on the Azure Paas

Tags: azure, paas, dianoga

I have implemented the Dianoga in my dev environment, while the final solution is deployed on azure paas.

```
Could not resolve type name: Dianoga.Invokers.MediaCacheAsync.Pipelines.Initialize.MediaCacheReplacer, Dianoga (method: Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).
```

I am getting this error on azure environment.  Has anyone encountered it? or seems familiar?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not resolve type name: Dianoga.Invokers.MediaCacheAsync.Pipelines.Initialize.MediaCacheReplacer, Dianoga (method: Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Exception: Could not resolve type name: Dianoga.Invokers.MediaCacheAsync.Pipelines.Initialize.MediaCacheReplacer, Dianoga (method: Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[Exception: Could not resolve type name: Dianoga.Invokers.MediaCacheAsync.Pipelines.Initialize.MediaCacheReplacer, Dianoga (method: Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).]
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Error.Raise(String error, String method) +133
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +1051
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +69
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +163
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert) +68
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetObjectFromType(XmlNode processorNode) +91
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetProcessorObject(XmlNode processorNode) +145
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CoreProcessor.GetMethod(Object[] parameters) +132
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +455
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +161
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +764
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +570
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +169
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +372
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +329

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not resolve type name: Dianoga.Invokers.MediaCacheAsync.Pipelines.Initialize.MediaCacheReplacer, Dianoga (method: Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +525
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +118
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +708

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2623.0
```

Answer (score 5):

If the targetframework of the project is lesser than 4.5.2 then try to upgrade the target framework and reinstall the Dianoga from nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dianoga/3.1.1

Also do check if Dianoga.dll is there in bin folder of the application.

Similar issue reported at

- https://github.com/kamsar/Dianoga/issues/22
- https://github.com/kamsar/Dianoga/issues/21